# What is the maximum size of deep learning model input size

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a data to train and test using Fully-connected Deep neural network FC-DNN; The size of the input data I should train is almost 3000,  first hidden layer should be up to 4096, third layer 4096 and finally the output layer should be 3000.

My question is the size of deep neural network is reasonable and acceptable?  What is the maximum reasonable size of deep neural network?

Comment: There are no *rules* to determine the number of neurons in each layer or the number of layers. You need to experiment with different number of neurons and layers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no maximum reasonable size (neither for neurons per layer nor for number of layers). After a specific point (which is really dependent on the problem you try to solve), you have diminishing returns when applying multiple `Dense` layers . In fact, it can lead to overfitting which should be avoided. At the same time, in absence of residual connections, stacking multiple `Dense` layers (making the network super-deep) could also lead to the vanishing gradient problem.

You should manually try to add a few layers and only if you see that your network does not perform well (low accuracy/other metric in your problem which is a sign of underfitting) should you add more layers.

Also, for the last layer I do not think that your problem requires 3000 neurons. If it is regression one neuron with linear activation will suffice. 3000 neurons are only needed if you have 3000 different classes (here we talk only about regression and classification).

Comment: Thank you ... The output neurons is something I'm working on it, it's a new model I try to optimize such function. ..    I can discuss with you about it.  Now, did you downvote  the question ? why . what's wrong with it ?

Comment: I posted it as new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135369/is-it-possible-to-use-a-part-of-data-for-cost-function-in-deep-learning-model . thank you in advance